# How to extract Genbank sequence and identify ORFs from the sequence in R?

Tags: r, fasta, genbank, orf

I used

```
ape::read.GenBank
```

and then used the function

```
ORFik::findORFs
```

to find ORFs in the sequence of interest. But the former one results in a `DNAbin` class format and the latter one requires `FASTA` format.

Is there a function available to convert the sequence from `DNAbin` class format to `FASTA` format?

(*I could think of directly downloading the FASTA format file and use the function.*)

Comment: You should be able to use ape's `write.dna()` function to output fasta format sequences